# Let $f$ be a non-zero holomorphic function with the property $arg(f(z)) = xy$. Find the function $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f = u + iv$, then $arg(f(z)) = \arctan \frac{v(z)}{u(z)}$. I tried deriving this equation and using the Cauchy Riemann equations, but I didn't find a way for it to help me finding $f$.

Then I was thinking if writing $f$ as $f(z) = |f(z)|(\cos(arg(z)) + i\sin(arg(z)))$ would be of any help, but without $|f(z)|$ it's also not to much help.

Could I ask for any tips on how to solve this problem? It seems I'm lacking something more obvious in my first try. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$
e^{z^2/2} = e^{x^2-y^2} e^{i x y} = e^{x^2-y^2} (\cos(xy) + i \sin(xy))
$$
has the property that $\arg e^{z^2/2} = xy$. It follows that $e^{-z^2/2} f(z)$ has the argument zero everywhere in the domain.

Now conclude that $e^{-z^2/2} f(z)$ is equal to some (real, positive) *constant.*